# Problem about MyBatis sqlMapGenerator auto generate

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I am trying to use MyBatis to create mapper, class etc. 
Although javaModelGenerator and javaClientGenerator are worked, sqlMapGenerator is not worked. Both have generated package, model, and mapper classes but sqlMapGenerator hasn't. I don't know and understand why.

Here is my generatorConfiguration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE generatorConfiguration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD MyBatis 
 Generator Configuration 1.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-generator- 
 config_1_0.dtd">
 <generatorConfiguration>
  <context id="context1">
   <jdbcConnection connectionURL="jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.com.au;databaseName=xxx" 
driverClass="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" password="xxxx" userId="xxxx" />
<javaModelGenerator targetPackage="com.mybatis.gokhan.model" targetProject="gokhan/src/main/java" />
<sqlMapGenerator targetPackage="com.mybatis.gokhan.sqlmap" targetProject="gokhan/src/main/java" />
<javaClientGenerator targetPackage="com.mybatis.gokhan.mapper" targetProject="gokhan/src/main/java" type="XMLMAPPER" />
<table schema="dbo" tableName="USER_ROLE">
  <columnOverride column="id" property="id" />
  <columnOverride column="date" property="date" />
  <columnOverride column="role_name" property="roleName" />
  <columnOverride column="last_update_date" property="lastUpdateDate" />
</table>
</context>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

After working console msg;

```
MyBatis Generator Started...
  Buildfile: C:\Users\Gokhan\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.mybatis.generator.eclipse.ui\.generatedAntScripts\gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2).xml
  11:37:46.282 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.eclipse.ui.ant.logging.AntLogFactory - Logging initialized using 'org.mybatis.generator.eclipse.ui.ant.logging.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingLogFactory@31e8fefd' adapter.
  11:37:46.296 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.logging.LogFactory - Logging initialized using 'org.mybatis.generator.eclipse.ui.ant.logging.AntLogFactory@50930c94' adapter.
  11:37:46.635 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Retrieving column information for table "dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.007 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found column "ID", data type 4, in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.008 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found column "DATE", data type 93, in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.008 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found column "ROLE_NAME", data type 12, in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.008 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found column "LAST_UPDATE_DATE", data type 93, in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.010 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found override for column "ID" in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.010 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found override for column "DATE" in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.010 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found override for column "ROLE_NAME" in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  11:37:47.010 [Worker-610: Launching gokhan-generatorConfig.xml (2)] DEBUG org.mybatis.generator.internal.db.DatabaseIntrospector - Found override for column "LAST_UPDATE_DATE" in table "xxx.dbo.USER_ROLE"
  BUILD SUCCESSFUL
MyBatis Generator Finished
```

Is there anyone can help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the generator no longer generates XML as it is not necessary when using the [MyBatis Dynamic SQL](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-dynamic-sql/docs/introduction.html) library.

See this page for details of how to use the generated objects: http://mybatis.org/generator/generatedobjects/dynamicSqlV2.html